# Параллельные эффекты в JQ

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Мне нужно применить к блоку одновременно и скольжение вверх и постепенную потерю непрозрачности. Однако, единственный известный мне метод позволяет это делать только последовательно. А как сделать 2 эффекта параллельно?

Известный мне метод )):

```
$('#g_notif').fadeOut(600).slideUp(600)
```

Answer (score 4):

Пример реализации нескольких эффектов параллельно, нужные добавить по вкусу:

```js
    // Произведем изменение нескольких css-величин в ходе одной анимации.
    $("#go").click(function(){
      $("#block").animate({ 
        width: "70%",         // ширина станет 70%
        opacity: 0.4,         // прозрачность будет 40%
        marginLeft: "0.6in",  // отступ от левого края элемента станет равным 6 дюймам
        fontSize: "3em",      // размер шрифта увеличится в 3 раза
        borderWidth: "10px"   // толщина рамки станет 10 пикселей
      }, 1500);               // анимация будет происходить 1,5 секунды
    });
```

```css
    div { 
      background-color:#bca; 
      width:100px; 
      border:1px solid green;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="go">» Съешь пирожок</button>

<div id="block">Алиса</div>
```

Comment: а скольжение вверх как добавить (slideUp, который встроенный эффект)? height:0?

Comment: Сделал так: $('#g_notif').animate({opacity:0, height:1},500); Но после анимации блок снова появляется в своих размерах, только прозрачный. А мне надо чтобы исчезал как после slideUp